# How to add rows to an object/table and then export to CSV/Excel in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm a noob when it comes to Powershell so i'm wondering how to solve this. Essentially, I have a script where I obtain details for a person using a foreach loop. The problem is, I want to put this into a table of columns and rows that looks like this:

| Age | eyecolour | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | green | male |

As it stands, I have a script which creates an object, but it's not right. The object is getting created per person and I don't want that. I need rows to be added per person. Also it's not in table format and needs to be exported to Excel. Any ideas on the best approach?

Thanks.

```
$people = #variable containing multiple people

foreach ($person in $people){

$age = #some get command
$eyecolour = #some get command
$gender = #some get command 

$object = new-object psobject -Property @{
                  age = $age
                  eyecolour = $eyecolour
                  gender = $gender 
                  }
Write-Host $object
}
```

Comment: If you want to export with an Excel format (`.xlsx`) then I recommend you to install the [ImportExcel Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel), or you can use `Export-Csv` for plain text formatted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question as asked, at least the part about "per person" you probably want an array of objects as follows:

```
Clear-Host

$People   = "Joe","Jane","Dick"
$MyTable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

ForEach ($person in $People){

  $Age       = Read-Host "Enter $Person's Age"
  $EyeColour = Read-Host "Enter $Person's Eye Color"
  $Gender    = Read-Host "Enter $Person's Gender" 
  
  $object = new-object psobject -Property @{
                    Name      = $Person
                    Age       = $Age
                    Eyecolour = $EyeColour
                    Gender    = $Gender 
                    }
  
  $Null = $MyTable.Add($Object)

} #End ForEach

$MyTable | Format-Table
```

Output:

```
Enter Joe's Age: 34
Enter Joe's Eye Color: Blue
Enter Joe's Gender: Male
Enter Jane's Age: 23
Enter Jane's Eye Color: Hazel
Enter Jane's Gender: Female
Enter Dick's Age: 54
Enter Dick's Eye Color: Brown
Enter Dick's Gender: Male

Gender Name Age Eyecolour
------ ---- --- ---------
Male   Joe  34  Blue     
Female Jane 23  Hazel    
Male   Dick 54  Brown
```

Note: Read-Host entries for demo only.

As for the part about Exporting to CSV  I agree with Santiago's comment.

Update:
Here's the code to create the CSV:

```
#Code to export Array of PSCustomObjects to CSV
$EPCSVArgs = @{NoClobber         = $True
               NoTypeInformation = $True
               Append            = $True
               Path = "G:\Test\MyTable.csv"}

ForEach ($Entry in $MyTable) {

  Export-Csv @EPCSVArgs -InputObject $entry 

}
```

Note: for some reason the CSV has the columns out of order!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2) and [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) commandlets?

Also, I agree with Santiago's comment about the ImportExcel module if you want to work with Excel.

Ex:

```
$p = @(
    (New-Object psobject -Property @{age = 5; eyecolour = 'blue'; gender='male'})
    (New-Object psobject -Property @{age = 10; eyecolour = 'brown'; gender='female'})
)

$p | format-table
$p | Export-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\p_out.csv"
```